# Как отловить различные ошибки записе в базу данных

Tags: php, laravel

```
Как ловить и обработать ошибки при создании новой записи ?


 public function store(Request $request)
    {

     $dela=new Dela();
     $dela->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
     $dela->nazva=$request->nazva;
     $dela->tip=$request->tip;
     $dela->vhod_v_delo=$request->vhod_v_delo;
     $dela->comment_k_delu=$request->comment_k_delu;
     $dela->status=$request->status;
     $dela->opisanie=$request->opisanie;
     $dela->country_id=$request->country;
     $city=City::findOrFail($request->city);
     $dela->tekuschiy_status=$request->tekuschiy_status;
     $dela->city_id =$request->city;
     $dela->city=$city->name;
     if(!empty($request->str_images)){
         $dela->images=$request->str_images;
     }
     $dela->bydzet=$request->bydzet;
     $dela->vremya=$request->vremya;
     $dela->effekt=$request->effekt;
     $dela->dlya_chego=$request->dlya_chego;
     $dela->blagodarnost=$request->blagodarnost;
     $dela->vhod_v_delo=$request->vhod_v_delo;
     $dela->save();
     $event=new Event();//add event data
     $event->type_id=1;//id delo_type
     $event->title=Auth::user()->name.' добавил новое дело - '.$dela->nazva;
     $event->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
     $event->save();
      return redirect()->route('profile.mydelo');


    }
```

Comment: В вашей моделе, которая отвечает за запись в БД делаете необходимые проверки,
если проверки не прошли, выбрасываете исключение. В него можно передать нужный 
пояснительный текст:
    if (...) {
        throw new \Exception('Заголовок неверный .... ');
    }
    if (...) {
        throw new \Exception('Ошибка .... чего-то там');
    }
В контроллере ловите исключение с помощью оператора 
try {
    $event=new Event();
    // ... code
    $event->save();    
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     // реализация нужной вам логики в случае обнаружения ошибки
 }

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Какие конкретно ошибки, и для чего?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно обернуть все конструкции в `try {...} catch {...}`. Надо также понимать, как устроена работа с базой данных. Если это реализовано механизмом PDO (что сейчас самое актуальное), то исключения (критические ошибки) бросают `PDOException`. Для активации этого режима даже на малейшие ошибки, которые выбрасывают `Error` можно указать `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Подробнее можно узнать на [PDOException](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.pdoexception.php) и [Ошибки и их обработка](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.error-handling.php).

Comment: при чем здесь PDO?

Comment: На будущее - если видите метку laravel - пропустите этот вопрос. Вы все равно не сможете дать осмысленный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Общие ошибки в контроллерах и запросах можно ловить  try {...} catch {...}
Но в Вашем случае у вас может быть 2 вида ошибки - подключение к бд если она на другом сервере и сервер отвалился например, или ошибки Валидации которой у вас вообще нет.

Добавьте верную валидацию на реквест в соответвии со структурой вашей базы данных пример:

```
$request->validate([
  'nazva' => 'required|string|max:255', //если у вас поле варчар
  'city' => 'required|integer', //если интегер
]);
```

Тогда в случаае ошибки система выбросит ее в сессию, поймать ошибку во вью ( а как я понял вам она там и нужна, т.к. в другом случае Вам придется использовать фасад валидатор use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;) можно так:

```
<!-- /resources/views/post/create.blade.php -->

<h1>Create Post</h1>

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<!-- Create Post Form -->
```

У Вас чень много ошибок, думаю изза не понимания сути отношений, вам обязательно нужно разрбратся с отношениями и у вас многое станет на свои места

Например зачем записывать в модель Dela и ид города и имя, если в отношении по ид можно вызвать любое поле? Тоесть зная основу отношений ( причем вам на данном этапе все не нужны а лишь 1 к 1, 1 ко многим, и возможно многие ко многим на вырост так сказать и все) Вам будет достаточно данного синтаксиса:

```
public function store()
    {
      //можно использовать синтаксис валидатора через точку только измените имена передаваемых параметров соответвенно например name="dela[nazva]"

      $data = request()->validate([
        'dela.nazva' => 'required|string',
        'dela.tip' => 'required|string',
        'dela.vhod_v_delo' => 'required|string',
        'dela.comment_k_delu' => 'required|string',
        'dela.status' => 'required|string',
        'dela.opisanie' => 'required|string',
        'dela.country_id' => 'required|integer',
        'dela.tekuschiy_status' => 'required|string',
        'dela.city_id' => 'required|integer',
        'dela.bydzet' => 'required|string',
        'dela.vremya' => 'required|string',
        'dela.effekt' => 'required|string',
        'dela.dlya_chego' => 'required|string',
        'dela.blagodarnost' => 'required|string',

        'dela.name' => 'sometimes|string',
        'dela.str_images' => 'sometimes|string',

        'event.type_id' => 'required|string',
        'event.title' => 'sometimes|string',
    ]);

    // $city=City::findOrFail($request->city);
    if(empty($data['dela']['name'])){
      $data['dela']['name'] = 'Нету названия города потому что я послал ид в реквесте и буду вызывать название через модель например $dela->city->name';
    }

    if(empty($data['event']['title'])){
      $data['event']['title'] = auth()->user()->name.' добавил новое дело - '. $data['dela']['nazva'];
    }

    $dela=auth()->user()->delas()->create($data['dela']);
    $event=auth()->user()->events()->create($data['event']);

    return redirect()->route('profile.mydelo');
    }

Правда для того что бы мой код ожил Вам таки придется почитать про Отношения и добавить их в модели но без этого вы все равно будете страдать, или используйте мой ответ на другой Ваш вопрос за основу, там есть пример связи 1 по многим в отношении юзера
```